# How to disable list in the rSubsection?

Tags: lists, cv, resume

I am working on my resume, and I want to use `srSubsection` environment. The problem is the current class file only allows entering a list. And I do not know how to modify that to allow inclusion of text or tables. Here is the code of subsection. Would you please help me modify it?

Thanks a lot.

```
 \newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you seek?  I just use the definition you gave, and add a tabular within the `\item`. (I also removed a stray space from your definition.

If you don't like the leading bullets, you can invoke the item as `\item[]`

EDITED to show various possibilities within the existing list environment.  In job 1, I show how to add a tabular and multiple items of detail.  In jobs 2 and 3, no details are given, only a summary.  Piggybacked onto the end of job 3 is an `\item[]` which I use to provide an even more concise summary of jobs 4-6.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{% 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{rSubsection}{Company Name, LTD}{2000-2004}{Mechanical Engineer}{Anytown, USA}
\item my blah blah blah experience goes here

\hfil\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & C\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hfil

\item I also did this...
\end{rSubsection}

\noindent%
\begin{rSubsection}{McDonalds}{1999-2000}{Cook}{Anytown, USA}
\item[]\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}
\end{rSubsection}

\noindent%
\begin{rSubsection}{Self employed}{1997-1999}{babysitter}{Smalltown, USA}
\item[] Prior to 1999 I did the following odd jobs after school

\hfil\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
lawn cutter & 1994 \\
\hline
rocket scientist & 1995 \\
\hline
atomic physicist & 1995 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hfil
\end{rSubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Actually since I have page limitation I don't want to have that line of `\item my blah blah...`. Then I get the error message.

Comment: @anna How about staring out with just one `\item[]` followed by whatever you want, up to and including multiple paragraphs?  I'm not sure how eliminating the `list` environment will save you any space in the output.

Comment: Yes, \item[] works well. I was just wondering if there is a way to change the .cls file for general purposes. Thanks.

Comment: @anna The problem is you provided us no minimum working example (MWE), but only a code snippet.  So we don't even know what class you are using.  I could only use the information you provided.  Finally, please see my revision of 6 minutes ago where I show several more use cases.