# Items ignoring spacing

Tags: spacing, formatting

I am trying to make a list like this:

```
...
\begin{rSubsection}{Europebet}{September 2017 - Present}{Quality Assurance Specialist}{Tbilisi, Georgia}
    \item Analysed software products including gambling games, casinos and tournaments.
    \item Tested programs for bugs and errors.
    \item Evaluated products' user-friendliness.
\end{rSubsection}
...
```

but text appears just on the same spacing as everything else and the bullets are a bit left. I want bullets to be aligned with other part and text to be a bit righter. What can I do?

Comment: What is `rsubsection`? `Resume subsection`? How is it defined?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your input may be legal with some document class, but nobody except you knows which one.

Comment: It should be noted that \item normally  starts with \unskip.

Comment: Does the answer below solved your problem? If yes you could ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have defined `rSubsection` environment as it is defined in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209627/how-to-disable-list-in-the-rsubsection).

In order to remove the additional space of the first line, I have removed a space from the environment definition and also used `\noindent` to make sure that there is no more indentation. You may precise the alignment of the items by modifying `\begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=`**2em**`}` as well.

Here is my solution for your problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{%  
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} 
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ 
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4}
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=2em}
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} 
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} 
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{rSubsection}{Europebet}{September 2017 - Present}{Quality Assurance Specialist}{Tbilisi, Georgia}
    \item Analysed software products including gambling games, casinos and tournaments.
    \item Tested programs for bugs and errors.
    \item Evaluated products' user-friendliness.
\end{rSubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]