# Indenting an \item within rSubSection

Tags: indentation

I have an rSubSection with several \item in it. For example here:

```
\begin{rSubsection}{Title}{}{}{}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{rSubsection}
```

I want to indent 'B' and 'C'. This is part of a broader project so I can't enumerate the items because that changes the overall format. How can I just push the second and third items in a bit? I feel like this is really simple but I can't find anything that works.

Comment: You should provide the community with your definition of this infamous `rSubsection` environment. Additionally, what would be helpful is a minimal document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, allowing us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly the output you're currently seeing. It'll aid in getting solutions to you sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are referring to [this definition of rSubSection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209627/how-to-disable-list-in-the-rsubsection), there is a simple but not too elegant fix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209627/how-to-disable-list-in-the-rsubsection
\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{% 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{rSubsection}{Title}{}{}{}
\item A 
\vspace*{-0.2em}
\begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=1em} % <- change identation here
\item B
\item C
\end{list}
\end{rSubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to draw more attention to your question, consider including an MWE in your post.