# ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. - when adding a \textbf

Tags: lists, subsection

I downloaded a C template and I'm using it to write my CV. In the "working experience" section, I decided to add a bold line using `\textbf` to categorise experience under the relevant transferable skill gained. In the first `rSubsection` of my CV (see Project management), it worked. In the second `rSubsection` as shown below (Technical skills), the first `\textbf` line gives me an error. The second one (Teamwork) works just fine!

```
\begin{rSection}{Working Experience} 
\begin{rSubsection}{University of city}{November 2021 - Present}{Postdoctoral Researcher}{city, country} 
\textbf{Project Management} 
\item Leading a research project 
\item Delivered project milestones on time. 
\end{rSubsection}

\begin{rSubsection}{University of city}{October 2016 - October 2019}{Imaging Scientist}{City, Country}

\textbf{Technical Skills} %the moment I use this line I get an error on the line below
\item Lab Maintenance: microscope setup, restocking of basic consumables.

\textbf{Teamwork}
\item Sharing expertise with undergraduate and postgraduate students

\end{rSubsection}
```

Error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.73 \item M
            aintenance: microscope setup, restocking of basic consumables.
```

Here is the template part as well:

```
%   SECTION FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}

% The below commands define the whitespace after certain things in the document - they can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\namesize{\huge} % Size of the name at the top of the document
\def\addressskip{\smallskip} % The space between the two address (or phone/email) lines
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\nameskip{\bigskip} % The space after your name at the top
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section
```

There is no `\item` missing, so there must be some issue with the `\textbf` that I'm adding, but I can't understand how it works sometimes, and sometimes not!

Comment: don't add text before the first \item command, \item  should be the first thing in a list. (your second \textbf is at the end of the first item, that's why it doesn't error).

Comment: That would make sense, however, on the first subsection it worked fine: \begin{rSection}{Working Experience}

\begin{rSubsection}{University of city}{November 2021 - Present}{Postdoctoral Researcher}{city, country}
\textbf{Project Management} 
\item Leading a research project
\item Delivered project milestones on time.
\end{rSubsection}

Comment: sorry but you didn't provide a complete example so I can't test.

Comment: apologies, I edited my original question, hopefully that is now showing the issue.

Comment: Dear Anna, please make from your codes fragment complete, small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with \end{document} which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The OP code is a modified version (adding a `rSection` environment`) from a [code provided by Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209629/132405) in answer to [How to disable list in the rSubsection?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209627/how-to-disable-list-in-the-rsubsection).

In the linked code, you can insert text or tables in the `rSubsection` environment. Not only `\item`'s.

But the first thing in the `rSubsection` environment needs to be an `\item`.

You can hide the bullet in the list item with `\item[]`.

To prevent all to be in bold face, I have added a `\normalfont` in the code of the `rSection` environment.

I have also removed the definitions of `\namesize`, `\addressskip`, and `\nameskip` not used in the OP code.

The OP missed the `\usepackage{ifthen}` so I add it (needed for `\ifthenelse`).

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
%   SECTION FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \normalfont\item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}

% The below commands define the whitespace after certain things in the document - they can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section

\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Working Experience} 
\begin{rSubsection}{University of city}{November 2021 - Present}{Postdoctoral Researcher}{city, country} 
\item[] \textbf{Project Management} % added a \item[] because we need here an \item, but the bullet is hidden with the blank option []
\item Leading a research project 
\item Delivered project milestones on time. 
\end{rSubsection}

\begin{rSubsection}{University of city}{October 2016 - October 2019}{Imaging Scientist}{City, Country}

\item[] \textbf{Technical Skills} % added a \item[] because we need here an \item, but the bullet is hidden with the blank option []
\item Lab Maintenance: microscope setup, restocking of basic consumables.

\textbf{Teamwork} % \item[] not needed here. Moreover, without the `\item[]` here, a slight vertical space (welcomed) is added.
\item Sharing expertise with undergraduate and postgraduate students

\end{rSubsection}
\end{rSection} % <-- added (missing in the OP code)

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** The code from Steven B. Segletes is used in [this tutorial](https://drshika.me/2022/04/15/latex-resumes) from Drshika Asher in order to make a Resume in LaTeX. This can gives this layout:

[image]

(unrelated with the code provided by the OP, but in the tutorial from Drshika Asher, the last code example miss `\item[]` before `\textbf{Coursework:}`. Also, in the provided Overleaf project with the complete code, some `\item[]` are missing: at line 100, 128, 133, 142).